# fzero cannot handle discontinuities

Tags: matlab, function

Consider the following function:

```
fun=@(x) tan(x);
x = NaN*ones(100,1);             % Initializes x.
starting_points=linspace(0,4*pi,100);
for i=1:100
% Look for the zeros in the function's current window.
x(i)=fzero(fun, starting_points(i));
end
x_unique=x(diff(x)>1e-12)
```

The output of the function is:

> x_unique =
>
> -0.0000
>       1.5708
>       3.1416
>       4.7124
>       6.2832
>       7.8540
>       9.4248
>      10.9956

We know that this is not true as tan has only 5 roots namely 0, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi and 4*pi in the interval [0, 4*pi]. 
The problem is- fzero gives x value as output where the function becomes discontinuous. How to rectify this problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe `abs(tan(x_unique))<0.1`? Just look if the value is close to zero.

Comment: The issue is that fzero looks for points where the function changes sign, and tan() changes sign around (2n-1)pi/2.  It doesn't really have anything to do with being discontinuous.

Comment: @gariepy So, what should I do If want to get only zeroes a function?

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the workaround. Thanks to @daniel

```
k=1;
for i =1:size(x_unique)
    if abs(fun(x_unique(i))) < 0.01
        R(k)=x_unique(i);
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

Add this to the end of the code. This will give only the zeros of the given function.

Comment: You can use the second output argument of `fzero` to avoid evaluating `fun` a second time.